# Translate a SVG element relative to right of screen?

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to translate a SVG element relative to the right of the screen as opposed to the top left that is it's default?

```
<svg class="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text id="text" class="svgText">test text test text</text>
  <rect id="border" class="textOutlineBox" x="0" y="0" width="440.5" height="90"/>  
</svg>

#text, #border {
  transform-origin: right center;
}

#text {
  transform: translate(15vw, 20vh);
}

#border {
  transform: translate(10vw, 10vh);
}
```

When I do this it still moves from the left of the screen. Is there a way to get it to transform relative to the right side of the screen?

jsFiddle describing my problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wvcsy6hg/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use CSS `translate` (or `translateX` or `translateY`), you don't translate the element relative to the edge of the screen, but relative to where the element would be on the screen, were it not translated.

So if you want to move a SVG `rect` leftwards from the right of the screen, you first need to position it somewhere near to the right edge of the screen.

One way to do this might be to:

1. Give the `<svg>` element a `viewBox` so you have a parental width to work with
2. Subtract the `width` of the element from the `width` of the `viewBox`
3. Apply the value from 2. as the element's `x` value.

Now, with the `rect` over towards the right hand edge of the screen, you can translate it leftwards, by giving it a negative `translateX` value.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

svg {
width: 99vw;
border: 1px solid gray;
}

#border {
transform: translate(-10vw, 10vh);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 200">
<rect id="border" x="559.5" y="0" width="440.5" height="90" />  
</svg>
```